# I am stuck in a loop while processing hexadecimal data from file

Tags: c#, binary

I'm trying to take in a file which contains hex values to convert to binary but the file reader is not reading in the next lines and it is stuck in a loop.

---

Here is what the hex file looks like:

> 3c011001
>   34300000
>   8e080000

Below is the code I use to generate the output:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;

class MaddinClass 
{
    static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
         StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MachineCode.txt");
         string binary_from_file = sr.ReadLine();

         while(!sr.EndOfStream)
         {
             uint binary = Convert.ToUInt32(binary_from_file, 16);
             Console.WriteLine(binary);
         }
     }
}
```

I am getting a loop result like this:

> 1006702593
>   1006702593
>   1006702593

I expect it to move to the next line and store a new binary result, instead it just prints the same value repetitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup you're not really reading the file to the end. You've created your `StreamReader` object, and read the first line from the file. You then end up in an endless loop due to:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
```

Since you're loop body doesn't read any of the information from the stream, you're continuously processing the same line from the file you stored prior to entering the loop which is why you consistently see `1006702593`. If you convert that value back to hexadecimal from decimal, you'll see that it matches your first hexadecimal input of `3c011001`.

```
uint binary = Convert.ToUInt32(binary_from_file, 16);
```

Per the [Microsoft instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time) you should be assigning each line in the [condition clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) of your `while` loop. This will allow you to process each line individually until the end of the file, where `ReadLine` should return `null` since there is nothing left to read.

> This example reads the contents of a text file, one line at a time,
>   into a string using the `ReadLine` method of the `StreamReader` class.
>   Each text line is stored into the string `line` and displayed on the
>   screen.

I would also like to point out that the line above isn't converting to binary, but rather an unsigned integer (hence your value of `1006702593` instead of `111100000000010001000000000001`); you'll need to convert the result of that to string with base 2 representation, and unless you have a valid reason to use unsigned integers, I would used signed integers instead:

```
string binary = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(binary_from_file, 16), 2);
```

Below is a refactored copy paste from the link above to meet your needs:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(line, 16), 2));

Console.ReadLine();
```

In a nutshell, the code above follows the execution path below:

- Create the variable for storing each line.
- Create a new `StreamReader` object pointed at your file.
- Read each line from the file.

  - Print that line in a binary representation.
- Close the stream.
- Dispose of the stream.
- Suspend the `Console` to prevent it from closing automatically.